# Django REST Frameworking overfetching when using PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

My Django model:

```py
class Quest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character, blank=True)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
```

The DRF serializer:

```py
class QuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    characters = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quest
        fields = "__all__"
```

The problem that I am having is that when I am fetching the list of quests, that it executes a query like this:

```sql
SELECT ("quests_quest_characters"."quest_id") AS
"_prefetch_related_val_quest_id", "characters_character"."id",
"characters_character"."legacy_id", "characters_character"."name",
"characters_character"."subtitle", "characters_character"."avatar",
"characters_character"."avatar_crop", "characters_character"."text",
"characters_character"."is_npc", "characters_character"."is_hidden",
"characters_character"."dm_notes",
"characters_character"."campaign_id",
"characters_character"."created_at",
"characters_character"."updated_at" FROM "characters_character" INNER
JOIN "quests_quest_characters" ON ("characters_character"."id" =
"quests_quest_characters"."character_id") WHERE
"quests_quest_characters"."quest_id" IN (1281, 1280, 1279, 1278, 1277,
1276, 1275, 1274, 1273, 1272, 1271, 1270, 1269, 1268, 1267, 1266,
1265, 1264, 1263, 1262, 1261, 1260, 1259, 1258, 1257, 1256, 1255,
1254)
```

That is a big query with a lot of fields, even though only an array of character ids is given back in the JSON result, so why is it fetching all this information? It should just fetch this, I would imagine:

```sql
SELECT "character_id" FROM "quests_quest_characters" WHERE "quest_id" IN (1281, 1280, 1279, 1278, 1277,
1276, 1275, 1274, 1273, 1272, 1271, 1270, 1269, 1268, 1267, 1266,
1265, 1264, 1263, 1262, 1261, 1260, 1259, 1258, 1257, 1256, 1255,
1254)
```

My view:

```py
class QuestController(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QuestSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Quest.objects.filter(campaign_id=self.kwargs["campaign_id"]).prefetch_related("characters")
        
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(campaign_id=self.kwargs["campaign_id"])
```

I am using `prefetch_related("characters")` otherwise it's doing one query *per character* which can result in the view doing hundreds of queries if you have lots of quests that have lots of characters.

So my question is: can I make the query to fetch the characters simpler? I am only returning an array of character ids after all, so there should be no need to fetch the whole characters, inner joined with the quests_quest_characters table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible by specifying a queryset when prefetching the characters, and [**`only`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) fetching the primary key initially like this:

```
Quest.objects.filter(
    campaign_id=self.kwargs["campaign_id"]
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "characters",
        queryset=Character.objects.only('pk')
    )
)
```

Just a note though that this will do one query per character if any other field other than `pk` is accessed for the related characters. You can specify more fields with `only` in that case.

Comment: Thanks! But this is still doing a query on the characters table, inner joined with quests_quest_characters, right? That still seems like a waste since the character id is already contained right there in that table, but I guess the performance hit is also negligible.

Comment: Ah true. It seems it can be done if you use your own through model. Otherwise it looks like it's an internal thing in django to go this way.

Comment: If no better answers come along, I'll mark yours as expected, even though it's not the ideal solution I was hoping for. But I think you're right, not much to do here.